# How do I use the "nwjc" versions for Mac and Linux, on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, cross-platform, nwjs

NW.js has this feature it calls "Protect JavaScript Source Code": https://nwjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/For%20Users/Advanced/Protect%20JavaScript%20Source%20Code/

> The JavaScript source code of your application can be protected by compiling to native code and loaded by NW.js. You only have to distribute the compiled code with your app for production.

> JS source code is compiled to native code with the tool nwjc , which is provided in the SDK build.

> **The compiled code is not cross-platform nor compatible between versions of NW.js. So you’ll need to run nwjc for each of the platforms when you package your application.**

I downloaded the SDK distributions for Windows, Mac and Linux, and looked into the files inside them.

The Windows one has a "nwjc.exe" file, ready to be used and works. Good.

But the Mac and Linux ones have no .exe, but instead just a "nwjc" executable. This is obviously for running on macOS and Linux, respectively. Huh?

My used OS is Windows. I am developing my NW.js application on Windows, to be distributed on Windows, Mac and Linux. And I cannot run those Linux/macOS executables on a Windows system. But I have to do so, since they are for some reason not cross-platform.

This seems like a dead end to me. I either have to not "protect" my application (and thus have it stolen/copied/broken/hacked), or buy two separate computers (one expensive Mac and one PC for Linux) and do this step on those. Which of course defeats the whole point of "simple" cross-platform development.

Before you say so, I have tried running Linux in a VM and it's terrible. And Macs cannot even be legally emulated AFAIK.

Most likely, this is going to cause my application to be Windows-only, which is really sad since a major reason for going this route was to have "simple" cross-platformness which "just works".

Is there something I'm missing about this?

PS: I already do "crush" my code with Uglify-JS, before the "protection" stage.

Answer (score 1):

The source protection works by saving a copy of the application as it is currently running in the OS's memory. This means you must run the command on the actual operating system, so it can load the app into memory and then save it as a V8 snapshot (V8 is the JS engine used by Chromium/Node/NW.js).

You can use tools like VirtualBox or VMWare to emulate other OS's on Windows. Getting OSX to run in an emulator is a pain, but there are youtube tutorials to explain how. Linux is very easy though, I'd start there if you are unfamiliar. Though running your application on actual hardware and manually testing in each OS is always best.

If this is too cumbersome, then you may consider not worrying about source protection until later. You can still set up your app for distribution on the other OS's without needing to emulate them if you don't use this feature. Though again, always best to manually test on each OS.